# Python Sequential Downloads

Tags: python, recursion, download, web-crawler, wget

I am trying to download PDFs from my school server, but the way it is set up by the stupid IT department is that we have to click each link one by one and there are hundreds of PDFs on the same page with links.

How can I download using python or wget "2015-0001.pdf" "2015-0002.pdf" "2015-0003.pdf"

I have tried `wget --accept pdf,zip,7z,doc --recursive` but it only grabs the index.html file of the site and no actual files.

Comment: Can you post what you have so far and the specific error you're getting or problem you're having?

Comment: Have you tried reading the docs for `wget`? Maybe your IT department are smart enough to know that it's actually pretty simple to download all the links.

Comment: For example, when I use `wget --accept pdf,zip,7z,doc --recursive` it only grabs the index.html file and nothing else.

Comment: "Stupid IT department"? Did you expect them to create a web site for people not using a browser? It appears, since you did not show a URL for even one of the files, that you don't even know how to use the tools you chose.

Answer (score 1):

Use Scrapy: http://scrapy.org/

An open source and collaborative framework for extracting the data you need from websites. In a fast, simple, yet extensible way.

[Scrapy tutorial how to get started with website scraping](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.24/intro/tutorial.html)